# Why is the number of cantrips in the Starter Set pregenerated character sheets different from the number in the rulebook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, lost-mine-of-phandelver, pregenerated-characters

In the Starter Set rule book, it shows that the cleric has 5 cantrips (Guidance, Light, Resistance, Sacred Flame, Thaumaturgy), and the wizard has 6 (Dancing lights, Light, Mage hand, Prestidigitation, Ray of Frost, Shocking grasp).

Yet, the character sheets says that they have 3 and 4 cantrips respectively. Aren't cantrips lvl 0 spells?

The levelling up guide doesn't show that you can learn extra cantrips, so perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The cantrips listed as known on the character sheets are correct.

Page 23 of the Starter Set rulebook is a list of cantrips that *exist* in the Starter Set, not a list of cantrips the cleric and wizard know. A 1st-level wizard or cleric knows only three cantrips (though the wizard in the Starter Set has an extra known, as that is a bonus high elves get).  More are listed because you do learn new cantrips by levelling. Both the cleric and the wizard learn one new cantrip of choice at 4th level. This is detailed on the backs of the sheets rather than in the levelling guide.

Additionally, having a reference for cantrips not yet known by PCs is useful to the DM if they appear in play when cast by characters other than the PCs, or if found on scrolls in treasure, etc.

Comment: You are right about the "too many cantrips known". The Starter set wizard is a High Elf, which gets a bonus Wizard  cantrip as a racial feature.

Comment: @MrNattious Ah-ha! I knew I must be overlooking something. Thank you!